# Is it a bridge or facade pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

And I have C interface which contains A and B interfaces.

Which pattern is this implementing?

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private readonly IWebServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly IDatabaseProvider _dbProvider;

    public Service(IWebServiceProvider serviceProvider, IDatabaseProvider dbInteractionsProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _dbInteractionsProvider = dbInteractionsProvider;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Company> CompanySearch(string name)
    {
        return _dbProvider.CompanySearch(name);
    }

    public ValidationResult ValidateUser(Data data)
    {
        var result = _serviceProvider.ValidateUser(new ValidationData()
        {
            Company = data.CompanyName,
            Password = data.Password,
            Login = data.Login
        });
        return new ValidationResult() { ErrorMessage = result.ErrorMessage };
    }

    public bool ResetPassword(ResetPassword resetPassword)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GenerateURL(int id)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GenerateURL(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no pattern here. Its a class with methods on it. It implements an interface. This appears to follow the "class that does something" pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've provided implements the [IoC (Inversion of Control)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx) pattern.

Comment: More specifically, dependency injection.

Comment: Dependency injection is not a pattern. It is just one of the ways how to achieve IoC.

Comment: I guess any form of dependency injection is also a form of the Strategy pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To call it the bridge pattern, you need to see evolution paths along abstraction and implementation. Here, implementation evolution (by using different service providers and db providers) paths are seen. But abstraction evolution is not seen in the code given (even though it is possible).

Also, the service class uses two implementation classes related to two different matters. A bridge would ideally represent one thing.

So this is more closer to a facade.